# Why is it not a mandate to pass parameters in a function defined with arguments as *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python

I've defined a function as follows:

```
def func_tion(*args, **kwargs):
  
    print("hola")

func_tion()
```

O/P:

```
hola
```

Why does this not show any error?

Are `*args` and `**kwargs` optional?

Comment: The `*` in `*args` and `**kwargs` means "zero or more".

Comment: Why should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The syntax is the `*` and `**`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).  The names `*args` and `**kwargs` are only by convention but there's no hard requirement to use them.

You would use `*args` when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to your function, i.e. it allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function.  For example:

```
>>> def print_everything(*args):
        for count, thing in enumerate(args):
...         print( '{0}. {1}'.format(count, thing))
...
>>> print_everything('apple', 'banana', 'cabbage')
0. apple
1. banana
2. cabbage
```

Similarly, `**kwargs` allows you to handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance:

```
>>> def table_things(**kwargs):
...     for name, value in kwargs.items():
...         print( '{0} = {1}'.format(name, value))
...
>>> table_things(apple = 'fruit', cabbage = 'vegetable')
cabbage = vegetable
apple = fruit
```

You can use these along with named arguments too.  The explicit arguments get values first and then everything else is passed to `*args` and `**kwargs`.  The named arguments come first in the list.  For example:

```
def table_things(titlestring, **kwargs)
```

You can also use both in the same function definition but `*args` must occur before `**kwargs`.

You can also use the `*` and `**` syntax when calling a function.  For example:

```
>>> def print_three_things(a, b, c):
...     print( 'a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}'.format(a,b,c))
...
>>> mylist = ['aardvark', 'baboon', 'cat']
>>> print_three_things(*mylist)
a = aardvark, b = baboon, c = cat
```

As you can see in this case it takes the list (or tuple) of items and unpacks it. By this it matches them to the arguments in the function.  Of course, you could have a `*` both in the function definition and in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)(emphasis mine):

> If the form “`*identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a tuple receiving **any excess positional parameters**, defaulting to the empty tuple. If the form “`**identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a new ordered mapping receiving **any excess keyword arguments**, defaulting to a new empty mapping of the same type.

"Any excess" can include "no excess", meaning neither form imposes a required argument.